# Libcublas not found on Jetson Nano

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I installed libraries and tensorflow for my Jetson Nano as is written in this manual

[pyimagesearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/03/25/how-to-configure-your-nvidia-jetson-nano-for-computer-vision-and-deep-learning/)

But when I trying to import `tensorflow` in my virtualenvwrapper (python3) I'm getting this error message and I can't find solution anywhere....I think that my Cuda (jetpack version) is newer version and there is not a support for the old `Tensorflow (TensorFlow 1.13.1 )`. But I'm not sure. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
I have this in my library

```
$ /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcublas.so
>>> libcublas.so            libcublas.so.10         libcublas.so.10.2.2.89
```

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/suomi/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/suomi/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/suomi/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/suomi/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/suomi/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/suomi/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/suomi/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/suomi/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/suomi/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Make sure the library location is in the appropriate search path within the environment you are using

Comment: I have this `tensorflow
tensorflow_estimator
tensorflow_estimator-1.13.0.dist-info
tensorflow_gpu-1.13.1+nv19.3.dist-info
`
in my `/home/suomi/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` and `which python` says `/home/suomi/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/bin/python`

Comment: I'm able to import stuffs like `scipy` which I was installing  in the same time from the same page in my virtualenvwrapper